# Is there a way of making Banshee use FreeDB?

Tags: banshee, cd-ripping

Basically, Banshee currently uses MusicBrainz for CD Ripping, but some albums that I have haven't been in there, but have been in FreeDB, is there a way of making Banshee use FreeDB when I rip CDs?

Answer (score 1):

Currently no freedb extensions for banshee. Here is a list from freedb.org that may help you determine another app to assist your needs.

[FREEDB applications](http://www.freedb.org/en/applications__freedb_aware_applications.9.html)